# Мигают сепараторы в UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview, uikit

Есть ли способ убрать мигание сепараторов в таблице на iPhone 6/6+ используя автомасштабирование? Т е не выставлять в launch image сториборд или какой либо xib (чтобы включить родное разрешение на ios device)

Comment: может этот ответ поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681282/ios-8-uitableviewcontroller-separator-scrolling-render

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вы используете стиль `uitableview - grouped`. Используйте `plain` - должно помочь.